# Compute the automorphism group of $D_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, group-presentation

> This exercise will compute the automorphism group of $D_{10}$. The presentation of the group
> is $D_{10 }= <r, s |r^5 = s^2 = 1, s^{−1}rs = r^{−1}>$
>
> (a) (i)  Show that under any automorphism $σ : D_{10} → D_{10},$ $r$ can have a
> maximum of $4$ images, and $s$ can have a maximum of $5$ images.
>
> (ii)  Show that any combination of $φ(r)$ and $φ(s)$ above give an automorphism of$ D_{10}$. Hence prove that$ |Aut(D_{10})| ≤ 20.$
>
> (b)  Let $σ$ be the homomorphism defined by $r→ r$ and $ s → sr,$ and $τ$ be the
> homomrphism defined by $r→ r^2$  and $s → s$. Show that $Aut(D_{10})$ is generated by $σ$ and  $τ$.
>
> (c)  Show that $Aut(D_{10})\cong F_5.$

I tried part (a). for part (b) and (c) , by given $σ$ and  $τ$, I found associated permutation representation by labeling element in $D_{10}$ from $1$ to $10$ then I got

$σ=(6 \space 7 \space 8 \space9\space 10)$ and $\tau=(2 \space 3 \space 5 \space4)(7\space 8 \space 10\space9)$

and I know presentation of $F_5=<a,b|a^5=b^4=1,bab^{-1}=a^3>$

But $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is not equal to $\sigma ^3$. Is there anything wrong with my work? Please help me.

I think, If I define $σ$  by $r→ r$ , $ s → sr,$ and $τ$ by $r→ r^3$  , $s → s$ , I can find a isomorphism to $F_5$

Comment: You sure about part (a)(i)? I think $r$ can have maximum of $4$ images, and $s$ can have maximum of $5$ images. Can you double check?

Comment: @Ash Sorry about that .It is a typo.

Comment: It's OK. I'll try to explain it in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we can have this presentation for $F_{5}$, too. That is $F_5=\langle a,b|a^5=b^4=1,b^{-1}ab=a^3\rangle$. Now we can get the result, with those two mentioned generators.

Also the new generators  $\tau$ and $\sigma$, that you defined, work with the presentation  $F_5=\langle a,b|a^5=b^4=1,bab^{-1}=a^3\rangle$. So it depends on how we view $F_{5}$.

Comment: Can you explain how these two are equal?

Comment: Yup, of course. So you agree that since $a$ and $b$ are generators, $a$ and $b^{-1}$ are also generators. So we can see the presentation that you mentioned this way: $F_5=\langle a,b|a^5=b^4=1,bab^{-1}=a^3\rangle=\langle a,b,c|a^5=b^4=c^4=1,c^{-1}ac=a^3, c=b^{-1}\rangle=\langle a,c|a^5=c^4=1,c^{-1}ac=a^3\rangle$. Right?